# PHP: str_replace within a word/phrase

Tags: php

I am trying to set up a small script that can play youtube videos but thats kinda besides the point.

I have `$ytlink` which equals `www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WAOxKOmR90`

But I want to make it become `www.youtube.com/embed/3WAOxKOmR90`

Currently I have tried

```
$result = str_replace('https://youtube.com/watch?v=', "https://youtube.com/watch?v=", $ytlink);
```

But this returns it as standard

I have also tried

```
 preg_replace('/https://youtube.com/watch?v=/, '/https://youtube.com/embed/', $ytlink);
```

but both of these dont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using ugly regexes, I recommend using [parse_url()](http://php.net/parse_url) with [parse_str()](http://php.net/parse_str). This allows you to be flexible in the event that you want to change something or if Youtube decides to change their URL slightly.

```
$url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WAOxKOmR90';
// Parse the URL into parts
$parsed_url = parse_url($url);
// Get the whole query string
$query = $parsed_url['query'];
// Parse the query string into parts
parse_str($query, $params);
// Get the parameter you want
$v = $params['v'];

// Now re-build the URL how you want
echo $parsed_url['scheme'].'://'.$parsed_url['host'].'/embed/'.$v;
// Outputs: https://www.youtube.com/embed/3WAOxKOmR90
```

Comment: Thank you. This was a great help :)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$ytlink = 'www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WAOxKOmR90';
$result = str_replace('watch?v=', 'embed/', $ytlink);
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WAOxKOmR90';    
echo preg_replace('/.*?v=(\w+)/i', 'www.youtube.com/embed/$1', $url);
```